# Regular expressions preg_match with line breaks

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, line-breaks

I'm trying to match a string inside an HTML

for example I want to find the string inside `<strong> string </strong>`

what I'm doing is

```
preg_match_all('|\<strong\>(.*)\<\/strong>|',$html,$data);

echo $data[1][0];
```

it works when the string I want to search inside `<strong>` is not a line break
but if it has a line break, how can I do it?

**not working** example:

```
<strong>
line break string
</strong>
```

Comment: [Obligatory advice against using regular expressions to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/560648)

Comment: @Tomalak - You must be great at parties.

Comment: @PMV: I'm _the best_ at parties. Unfortunately, Stack Overflow is not a party. I'm pretty good here too, though.

Comment: @user983124: Please format your post.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use:

```
preg_match_all('/<strong>(.*)<\/strong>/s',$html,$data);
```